# MySQL combine two indexes into one

Tags: mysql, indexing

I was wondering if there is some way to combine two indexes into third to make sort of serial number... For example:
If I want to create music database
I would start with table artists with
-artist_name
-artist_id (Primary key)
-....

Then table albums with
-album_name
-album_id (P.k.)
-...

And then table songs with
-song_title
-song_id

Let's say artist would be X with artist_id - 12345
Then album Y with album_id - 678
And I want song_id to be 12345.678.xxx (dots only for visualization of the idea, length of artist_id and album_id would be constant)

My question is. Is something like possible?
Because I have a feeling that this would perform much more better search through database.
Not only that in my song_id I have full information of artist and album (I don't need to use foreign keys than), it should speed up any query about songs from the same album or other albums of the same artist. All information in one index and it needs only some kind of extraction.

Or maybe its just mine minimal knowledge about MySQL? :)

Comment: Well, I'll take a stab at starting, though I don't 100% understand where you're trying to go with this.  You can combine fields into both indexes OR primary keys (which is really a specialized index)  But the idea of a normalized data structure is to keep the size of the DB small, and help with maintenance, not reduce the reliance on foreign keys.  So, when Prince changes his name, again, you want to be able to update a single record in the Artist table, not 1000 records in the artist_album_song table.

Comment: Do you really mean "index" in the MySQL sense of the word? It seems like you haven't created any tables that actually define the relation between artist, song, and album. Those are essential for using a relational database. You really need to read about how to properly design the data model for your database.

Comment: Actually I'm not completely sure where I'm going with it but to be honest.. If Prince will change his name, albums that are already on the market will never change the names :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep artist_id and album_id as separate columns in the songs table and include proper foreign key relationships and indexes. This will give you the best combination of data integrity and query performance.

Comment: :) I was afraid I was delirious with it... :)